# code error in word2vec program for DNA sequence

Tags: python-3.x, list, word2vec, fasta

I have been trying to develop a code to read nucleotide in fasta format  as strings(each input as one word) and then use already known binding site sequences(11 bp long) to search amongst the nucleotide sequences through word2vec model

The fasta file looks like and all values are read in sequences as string

`sequences:

ATCGTGACGTGACGTGACGT

CGTAGCTAGAGCTAGCGGATCGA

and the binding sites are stored as a column in dataframe as df['binding']

ATGACTCAGCA

GTGACTAAGCA

ATGACTCAGCA

ATGACTCAGCA

...

Here is my code in python:

```
import gensim 
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sequences, size=2, min_count=len(sequences), sg = 1)
model.train(sequences,total_examples=len(sequences),epochs=10)
w1 = df['binding']
model.wv.most_similar(positive=w1)
```

I was hoping to get a relation between each binding sites but it throws error as `KeyError: "word 'ATGACTCAGCA' not in vocabulary"` here ATGACTCAGCA is the first value in `df['binding']`

If I change the `w1 = df['binding'] to w1='A'`, I get the results as

```
[('T', 0.9952122569084167),
 ('G', 0.9772425889968872),
 ('C', 0.9460670351982117)]
```

What should change to get relation between two binding sites and not two/more base pairs?

Comment: Have you tried iterating by row through your data frame while feeding each individual string into model.wv.most_similar()?

Comment: Iteration does not work, I have tried taking individual binding site values as well. nothing accept the single bp works here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure your `sequences` is a python sequence, where each item is a list-of-tokens, where the tokens are the 'words' you want to look up (such as multiple related 11-character 'binding sites'). If it's a sequence of strings with just 'AGTC' character, the tokens will just be  `A`, `G`, `T`, `C`.

A `size=2` probably won't generate interesting vectors, at least not for a vocabulary of hundreds or thousands of tokens.

A `min_count` as long as your full set of examples will throw away any token that doesn't appear at least that many times.

You don't need to call `train()` if you supplied the dataset to the class-initialization: it will have already launched training automatically. (If you're running with logging at the INFO level, this would be obvious from the output.)

Comment: I can not change the ```sequence``` from anything apart from ATCG because its a nucleotide sequence.

Comment: You need to supply the "words" of your domain (whatever those are) as lists-of-tokens for `Word2Vec` to work. If you just supply raw strings like "ATTGATCGCTAGCTCTAGCTGACTG", it can't work, because that's not the input `Word2Vec` expects, & the only tokens it will see are `A`, `G`, `T`, and `C` – & just 4 words aren't going to be helpful. It has to be more like a bunch of lists, like: `['ATTATC', 'AGTA', 'TCGCGA', 'CTCCAACG']`, so that it can learn relationships between such more-than-1-letter groupings. So you'll have to modify your `sequences` to match a meaningful `Word2Vec` input format.

Comment: Thanks, Its is much clear now but I have one more questions.. How to create this token for words. Also, the binding sites provided aren't just four I have a list of about 20000.

Comment: I'd need more info about the original format of your data, and this specific non-traditional-for-Word2Vec-problem-domain (DNA rather than human natural language), to know how to massage the original data into sentence-like "texts" that have DNA-ranges as "words". (Is there a form of the data where multiple 11-base-pair "binding sites" appear together, in order, analogous to a sentence with many 11-letter words?)